# J tacit phrase evaluation

Tags: j, tacit-programming

Why does `2(*i.)5` evaluate to `0 2 4 6 8` ?

It's clear that `2*i.5` does, but the `()` creates a hook and evaluating from right to left it seems we get

```
 (*i.)5  ==  0 5 10 15 20
```

and 2 won't act on that list -- so where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

`2 (* i.) 5`, is a dyadic hook, which translates to `2 * (i. 5)`.

`(* i.) 5`, is a monadic hook, which translates to `5 * (i. 5)`.

The dyadic hook, `x (u v) y` is equivalent to `x u (v y)`, which is the same as `x u v y`.

The monadic hook, `(u v) y` is equivalent to `y u (v y)`, which is the same as `y u v y`.

http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/hook

Comment: Good explanation.  The book I was reading didn't explain these cases (even existed) and just jumped straight to an example.  Now I know where to look !

Answer (score 3):

`x (u v) y` <--> `x u (v y)` for dyadic hooks.

A use might be to reshape y into the shape x as shown at 
http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/hook

```
   [t=.i. 3 2
0 1
2 3
4 5

   2 3 ($ ,) t
0 1 2
3 4 5
```